# how to integrate YELP API with iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing one iphone application in which I want to use yelp api.But I dont know how to integrate with iphone.I have found one sample code from the GIT hub but there are not specific code.Can you give me some advice or some reference.
Please give me solution for this query
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606572/how-to-integrate-yelp-api-in-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at RestKit http://restkit.org/
It's a great tool for connecting with API's like this.  Once you get that working it should be as simple as connecting and making some calls.