# How to integrate Yelp APi in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, yelp

I am developing an application. In that I want to use the Yelp Api. So after registering on Yelp site how to integrate that Api in our application. Please provide me any examples or any stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Documentation of Yelp 1.0 Search API:

  http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/search_api
- Documentation of Yelp 2.0 Search API:

  http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api
- General overview of Yelp APIs:

  http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation

With the above links, depending on your current skills, you might have to search and read about:

1. [Sending/handling a http
   request/response on iPhone.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http%20request%20%20response%20handling%20objective-c%20iphone)
2. [Parsing JSON response on
   iphone/Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parsing%20json%20response%20iphone%20%5Bobjective-c%5D)

Comment: Only that one line of code is sufficient for gertting the data from Yelp?

Comment: That one line is just the http request you need to send. You then need to handle the response from Yelp which is in JSON format by default.

Comment: You should be looking for 
`1.` sending/handling a http request/response on iPhone.
`2.` parsing JSON response on iphone/Objective-C

Comment: @Ozair can you please suggest me that where i can set my Yelp key in URL . Same like google Api (we can append APIKey with request .) .

Comment: my concern is that can we get response of Yelp API with direct URL only (Without integration of framework ). Please suggest me for this .

Comment: @iThink The authentication parameters can be passed in the HTTP (Authorization) header as URL query keys or in the POST data. Read more [here](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/authentication).